# Is there an R function better than I've used?

Tags: r

Question:
"Create a sequence of numbers from 1:10000 
and then deduct 10 from every number in the sequence
convert the negative numbers to positive
Round pi to 12 decimal figures"

Solution: 
abs(c(1:10000)-10)
round(pi,12)

Is there a better way to solve?

Answer (score 0):

But, how do you convert all the negative numbers in the output to 12-digit pi?

If - as I interpret the question - you want to decrease 1:1000 by 10 for each number in the range, and then replace all negative numbers in this output with 12-digit pi, you should use:

```
unlist(purrr::map_if(
  1:10000-10,
  ~.x<0,
  ~round(pi, 12))
)
```

In this code, the function map_if() (in the purrr package) applies the function "Replace by round(pi, 12)" to all objects in the range meeting the criteria "x<0", leaving the other values unchanged.

Do I interpret your instructions correctly?